# Count frequency of second element of tuple across rows

Tags: python, tuples, counter, frequency

I have a document containing >1000 instances of tuples. I want to calculate the frequency of the second element of the tuple across all rows, and then delete the tuples that belong to the "NN" group.

Here is my data:

| pos_tag |
| --- |
| [(semoga, SC), (saja, RB), (di, IN), (sini, PR), (bisa, MD), (cepat, JJ), (cair, NN), (semoga, NN), (saja, RB), (ini, PR), (beneran, NN), (ada, VB), (nya, NN), (bantuan, NN), (buat, JJ), (butuh, VB), (banget, NN)] |
| [(kak, VB), (kenapa, WH), (perbaikan, NN), (sistem, NN), (nya, PRP), (tidak, NEG), (selesai, VB)] |
| [(sangat, RB), (baik, JJ)] |

I would like to know the frequency, showing:

| tag | frequency |
| --- | --- |
| SC | 1 |
| RB | 3 |
| IN | 1 |
| PR | 2 |
| MD | 1 |
| JJ | 3 |
| NN | 8 |
| etc. | ... |

After deleting words that belong to NN, the data will be:

| pos_tag | pos_tag_clean |
| --- | --- |
| [(semoga, SC), (saja, RB), (di, IN), (sini, PR), (bisa, MD), (cepat, JJ), (cair, NN), (semoga, NN), (saja, RB), (ini, PR), (beneran, NN), (ada, VB), (nya, NN), (bantuan, NN), (buat, JJ), (butuh, VB), (banget, NN)] | [(semoga, SC), (saja, RB), (di, IN), (sini, PR), (bisa, MD), (cepat, JJ), (saja, RB), (ini, PR), (ada, VB),(buat, JJ), (butuh, VB)] |
| [(kak, VB), (kenapa, WH), (perbaikan, NN), (sistem, NN), (nya, PRP), (tidak, NEG), (selesai, VB)] | [(kak, VB), (kenapa, WH), (nya, PRP), (tidak, NEG), (selesai, VB)] |
| [(sangat, RB), (baik, JJ)] | [(sangat, RB), (baik, JJ)] |

Really need help, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `explode`, slice the second item, and `value_counts`:

```
out = (df['pos_tag']
       .explode()
       .str[1]
       .value_counts()
       .reset_index(name='frequency')
      )
```